# how to notify multiple user account using ajax

Tags: php, ajax

i am trying to send notification to user accounts by inserting records to the database with indication whether the record has been viewed or not using true or false. the problem is when the first user has seen the notfication the record in the database become true, then other users are unable to see it. here is my code below

```
if($_POST["view"] != '')
 {
  $update_query = "UPDATE notifier SET n_status=1 WHERE n_status=0";
  mysqli_query($conn, $update_query);
 }
```

Comment: Then you are going to have to create one row for each user you want to notify.

Comment: Shouldn't your update contain the specific id of the user who viewed the notification?

Comment: You need to create new column in which you will store data (if user has(not) seen it) for each user separately.
You can do it by adding new column to your current users table or by creating new table in which you will have 'user_id' and 'displayed' fields, referring to users by 'user_id'.

Comment: @PatrickQ is right, you are updating the whole table where `n_status=0`. You should query on user_id too (add the column if you don't have it already).

Comment: @Maelig so for example i have 20 users. i will insert record 20 times for each user id?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a column to link your notifications to your user table, so you `notifier` table should look like (it's an example, adapt it to your needs) ;

```sql
create table "user"(
    id uuid default public.uuid_generate_v4() not null
);

create table "notifier"(
    id uuid default public.uuid_generate_v4() not null,
    user_id uuid references user(id) not null,
    n_status int not null default 0
);
```

Now when you add a notification fo user with id `852f5ea9-0bad-4c0f-aab8-00479eae026f`:

```
insert into "notifier" (id, user_id, n_status) 
    values (public.uuid_generate_v4(), '852f5ea9-0bad-4c0f-aab8-00479eae026f', 0);
```

Then when this user has read the notification with id `ddf5fb8f-3100-4860-a61e-bae2a1393a8e`, you change the notification status.

```
update "notifier" set n_status = 1 
    where user_id = '852f5ea9-0bad-4c0f-aab8-00479eae026f'
    and id = 'ddf5fb8f-3100-4860-a61e-bae2a1393a8e'
```

For security I think it's better to change a status by it's `id` (coming from the client) and add `user_id` that cannot be faked by your client if you have a proper auth.